# consulta postgres con parámetros PDO

Tags: php

Estoy recibiendo un JSON con los distintos parámetros de unos selects y quería darle seguridad a la consulta que hago, ya que me parece un poco precaria. La consulta puede o no cumplir todos los criterios de búsqueda, por eso me está costando hacer una consulta preparada.
1º recibo el JSON con los parametros.

```
include 'dbConection.php';
$conn = new conexion();
$conex = $conn->getConexion();

$params = json_decode(file_get_contents('php://input'), true);

$date1 = $params["date1"];
$date2 = $params["date2"];
$name = $params["nombre"];

$query = "SELECT id, date1, date2, nombre, direccion, peso FROM table WHERE peso >= 10::numeric";

if($params["date1"]!= ""){
  $query .= " and date1 >= '$date1'";
}
if($params["date2"]!=""){
  $query .= " and date2 <= '$date2'";
}
if($params["nombre"]!=""){
  $query .= " and nombre = '$nombre'";
}

#como no tenía muy claro como preparala, puse fuera el prepare
$statement = $conex->prepare( $query );
```

Después hago el json_encode y saco el fichero.

Comment: Pon un ejemplo de cómo debería quedar la consulta final.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Podrías hacer lo siguiente:

1. Determinar el estado de los datos con un ternario, guardando referencia en variables.
2. Verificar si cada variable es nula o no, para agregar una condición a la consulta SQL, pero **usando marcadores de nombre** y al mismo tiempo ir asociando a un array (`$mParams`) el marcador de nombre y el valor.
3. **Dado que PDO admite pasar arrays en el `execute()`** puedes pasar `$mParams` en ese momento.

El código quedaría así:

```
include 'dbConection.php';
$conn = new conexion();
$conex = $conn->getConexion();
#Array para ir guardando los parámetros que pasaremos a execute
$mParams=array();

#Preferiremos un objeto a un array, por eso no pasamos true
#Y cambiamos el nombre para evitar confusiones (estos son datos, no parámetros en sí)
$mData = json_decode(file_get_contents('php://input'));

$date1 = !empty($mData->date1)  ? $mData->date1  : NULL;
$date2 = !empty($mData->date2)  ? $mData->date2  : NULL;
$name =  !empty($mData->nombre) ? $mData->nombre : NULL;


$query = "SELECT id, date1, date2, nombre, direccion, peso FROM table WHERE peso >= 10::numeric";

if($date1){
  $query .= " and date1 >= :date1";
  $mParams[":date1"] = $date1;
}
if($date2){
  $query .= " and date2 <= :date2";
  $mParams[":date2"] = $date2;
}
if($name){
  $query .= " and nombre = :nombre";
  $mParams[":nombre"] = $name;
}

#como no tenía muy claro como preparala, puse fuera el prepare
$statement = $conex->prepare( $query );

#Aquí pasamos $mParams
$statement->execute($mParams);
```